# I'm confused about the print out in python while loops

Tags: python

I thought the loop should end up with print out 23.1, why stop in 23.0? 23.0 still meet "if guess <= x", doesn't it?

My python version is 2.7

I'm a new learner, and stuck here, hope someone could explain it for me, many thanks.

```
x = 23
epsilon = 0.01
step = 0.1
guess = 0.0

while abs(guess**2-x) >= epsilon:
    if guess <= x:
        guess += step
        print guess
    else:
        break
if abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print 'failed'
else:
    print ('succeeded: ' + str(guess))
```

Comment: The numbers 0.1 and 0.01 don't actually exist in binary floating point; you're using the nearest possible approximations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop reaches the `break` line when `guess` is `23.000000000000057`, and that is greater than `23`. You might expect it to be `23.0` but [floating point numbers do not produce exact  arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).